# Node.js and Socket.io memory leak fixing

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io

In my multiplayer game we have just released an update using node.js and socket.io and we saw after some time that it has a memory leak.

I've read about Nodetime that it is a great program to check what is causing the memory leak.
I have made two snapshots, but now I don't know what to do...

[image]

Those two snapshots are made with 8 minutes in between. 
Seeing that it already grow 16MB in Retainer > Other... I'm clueless what it could be.
The count is also a very huge number. All those large instances are buffers, but I can't remember that I've used buffers myself, is it in socket.io?

Can someone enlighten me, or at least give some tips where to look?

Comment: maybe [this article](http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/) can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at **[Tracking down a memory leak in Node.js and Socket.IO](http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/)** if you are using Node.js v0.8.21 and Socket.IO v0.9.13.

Comment: That's the same link that I posted in the comments three hours earlier.

Comment: Oh, I'm deeply sorry I didn't saw your comment. I think you should have created an answer as it may really be the cause of the issue since @Martin said he recently updated NodeJS & socket.io.

Comment: Hi guys, both thanks a lot for the article! I have applied the fix suggested to my socket.io and it seems the buffer objects are gone for the most part! (without influencing my application) But now I still have memory issues, for what I've seen now. I hope to have more information tomorrow.

Comment: I've found the other memory leak, it was totally my own fault :) Thanks again for the links, I'll accept is as answer since this was definitely another memory leak I was having.